# Replace row names in an SQL statement with informations from an other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table named data where the name of a column is field_id_# (where # is a number from 1 to 129). I also have another table named fields with columns field_id (with only the # of the corresponding field in table data - That means just the number # not field_id_#) field_name and field_label. Now I would like to run a query like this:

```
SELECT data.field_id_1 AS fields.field_label1,
       data.field_id_2 AS fields.field_label2
       [...]
```

I don't know if this is possible or not and if so, how to do it.
Can someone help me with that?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: it can be done with dynamic query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an example how to do it? I tried `SET @table = 'DESCRIBE data'; SELECT Field FROM @table` But this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please use the meaningful names directly for your column definitions! All your selects and program parts that access the database will be readable. They're surely not readable with the naming convention you describe here.

For an immediate solution you can build the SQL Statement dynamically/programmatically, or you generate views where the columnnames are replaced with the meaningful ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't change them, because I didn't build the DB. I just need to use data out of it...

Comment: You're just the victim of a bad designed database. In this case I would build views withthe meaningful names and use them on all cases (insert, update, delete, select) when possible.